# Java input stream to read deserialized ArrayList with specified type result in Object array

Tags: java, arraylist, casting, deserialization

An http request is sent from an android to a servlet. An ArrayList is serialized as an object as a response.

On Server side,

```
ArrayList<catAryList> catAryList=new ArrayList<>();
catAryList.add(cat1);
catAryList.add(cat2);
OutputStream outStream=_resp.getOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream objOutStream=new ObjectOutputStream(outStream);
objOutStream.writeObject(catAryList);
```

On the client side,

```
InputStream inputStream =httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
rtnValue = (ArrayList<Cat>) is.readObject();
```

I have checked the rtnValue from the debugger. Instead of an ArrayList, it is an Object[]. Also, the fields of each object are also in Object[]. The content of the fields and the number of Object are correct.

How can I cast the Object[] to ArrayList correctly, instead of copying each field to build a new instance of Cat and add these Cats to a new ArrayList?

Thanks

Comment: You can't _cast_ an array to an `ArrayList` — you _need to_ construct a new `ArrayList` instance (one way or another). Same for `Cat` - you can't just cast an array or a map to a custom class. Would fixing serialization on server side be an option?

Comment: Sure, how should I change my server code to make the casting better on the client side? Thanks

Comment: You should simply forget about using native serialization. It's fragile, especially between two different JVMs. Use JSON.